# How to use dnSpyEx or some other .NET debugger to attach to a .NET process started with a process-hollowing technique?

Tags: debugging, unpacking, .net, packers, dnspy

I have a .NET executable that is started using the [process-hollowing](https://www.ired.team/offensive-security/code-injection-process-injection/process-hollowing-and-pe-image-relocations) technique. Here's how it looks from the Detect-It-Easy tool:

[image]

I can open the image file for that process (from disk) with dnSpyEx, but when I try to attach to it with a debugger while it's running (after it was process-hollowed), my breakpoints don't hit:

[image]

Any idea how to attach to such process with a debugger - dnSpy or some other one?

Answer (score 3):

You can insert an infinite loop in the code that you can find once you attach to the process.

1. Right click the method you want to put a breakpoint on and select `Edit Method`.
   [image]
2. Add an infinite loop  inside an `if` before the code where you wanted to put the breakpoint: `bool a = true;if(a){while(true){}}`. Click `Compile`.
3. Save module.
4. Run the sample as desired.
5. Attach to the process with DnSpy (you may need to run it as admin) and pause (`Break all`) the debugger, which will stop at the infinite loop.
6. The instruction where you wanted to put the breakpoint is the first after the `else`. Right click this instruction and select `Set Next Statement`.
   [image]

---

This is similar to the [`EBFE` technique](http://paulslaboratory.blogspot.com/2014/04/ebfe-debugging-remote-thread.html).

Note that the definition of `bool a = true;` and the `if` surrounding the `while(true)` is needed to trick the debugger to avoid that compilation remove the rest of the code. If the compiler is still able to remove it, you can try a bit more difficult condition to trick the debugger such as `int a = 3; int b = 2; if(a*2-b+1==5){while(true){}};`

Comment: Hmm, that's an interesting idea. But how would I insert my code into it if my breakpoints don't hit? See that second screenshot.

Comment: You need to insert the code before the sample is run. Note running the sample is step 4.

Comment: Thanks. That's an interesting technique. I tried it, but step 5 doesn't produce the result that you described. The dnSpy breaks but then it doesn't switch to the source code line. And even if I click "Show next statement", nothing happens. My guess is that it can't find symbols.